# Bootstrap responsive - Ignore 'spanX' when viewing on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Let's say I have a website which uses Twitter Bootstrap and has the responsive features included. In this example, I have a div with a picture in a div with `span1` as the class, and some text in a div with `span11` as the class. I don't want to display the image while the site is being viewed from a mobile phone. Here's the code I would use:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span1 hidden-phone">
    <img src="path/to/image">
  </div>

  <div class="span11">
    <p>Here is some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

From this example, the `span1` div is hidden if the site is visited from a mobile phone, however the `span11` div is still visible.

If I use this code, will the contents of `span11` span across the entire width of the page (given that it's being viewed on a mobile phone), or will it still only span across 11 out of 12 spaces on the Bootstrap grid? If this is the case, how can I specify that I want the paragraph in `span11` to span *the entire width of the page* and not just 11 out of 12 spaces as defined by the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will span the entire width.

The `css` of Bootstrap converts all elements with a `span*` class to block elements with 100% width for devices with screen width less than `767px`; consequently, there's not really a 'grid' for mobile.

Here's the code that does this:

```
[class*="span"],
.uneditable-input[class*="span"], // Makes uneditable inputs full-width when using grid sizing
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    .box-sizing(border-box);
  }
```

Source: [The Bootstrap mobile layout .less file, line 60](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-767px-max.less#L60)

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer, that's just what I was looking for :)